# Get values into an array outside an if condition statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to write a function that get filtered & calculated values using if-statement out and store in an array which later uses in another if statement:

```
def myfunction(csv_File,search,x,y):
first_line = True
count_row = 0

for data in open(csv_File):
    if first_line:
        first_line = False
    else:
        count_row += 1
        data_values = data.split(",")
        Search = data_values[0].lower()
        x_coordinate = float(data_values[1])
        y_coordinate = float(data_values[2])
        class = data_values[3]
        
    
    coordinates = []  
    for i in range(count_row):            
        if Search == Search.lower():
            #coordinate
            coordinates.append([x_coordinate,y_coordinate])
            aQ = coord[0][0]
            lQ = coord[0][1]
            coordinates.append(x)
            coordinates.append([aQ+d1,aQ-d1,lQ+d2,lQ-d2])

            #Only works inside if-condition...
            return coordinates

        #Trying to get filtered values outside the if-condition to store in "coordinates"
        return coordinates
        
myfunction("location_search.csv","ID_391", 1,1)
```

at the last part calculated-values are not able to return outside the if condition (`if Search == Search.lower()`) which I am trying to use to compare with the rest of data values within the csv file.

So are there ways to get filtered values out of an if statement, store into an array outside which can be use for comparing values in another if statement or so?

Comment: Your code logic only returns  last a result of for. Are you sure?

Comment: Since you declare `Search =data_values[0].lower()` therefore `if Search == Search.lower()` will always be true and you return early.

Comment: if Search == Search.lower() is trying to check if the input ID can be found in the column of IDs inside the csv file. If as expected, get the corresponding x,y coordinates which I trying to store to the array outside the if-filter then use them to compare in a new if-statement..

Answer (score 0):

if you want to filter out the results that should not match the `if` statement

```
return [coord for coord in coordinates if Search != Search.lower()]
```

Does it make sense?

Comment: The values still only accessible inside that if statement even with this return called at the end..